# How I can delete event using event's date in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I try to delete an event using event's date. I see in [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/) like the following

> idOrFilter may also be a filter function that accepts one Event Object
>   argument and returns true if it should be removed.

So, I just try like the following

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.start);
```

It's no difference with removing with id.

Why I try to remove using event date is I have an event and it can be drag and drop to the calendar's difference date. Like [this example](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.3/demos/external-dragging.html). And I just want to delete event from specific date. But now it's just removing all the events. I appreciate all of helps.

Comment: Set a unique ID to each of your events and pass those IDs to the removeEvents call.

eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {           
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the ID of the event object that you want to remove.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', "ID");
```

If you do not specify any ids, it will simply remove all events.

Comment: I have unique date. How I can try with date? Not with the id.